# d3 multiple svg with 1 row of data each

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm stuck with a d3.js issue: 
I'm trying to draw several SVG canvas with a LINE (it's a more complex custom shape, but as an example the line is sufficient), where the length (called "d.uni") of the line is determined by data. So, each row of the data is mapped to a line within its own SVG.

I looked at the examples that are out there for multiple SVG, like http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1305111 and http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3888852 and adapted the idea, which is mainly – as far as I get it – to bind data to the SVG drawing function.

Here is my code:

```
     var w = 300;
     var h = 250;
     var stemL = 100;
     var length1 = 80;
     var angle1 = -1.2;

d3.csv("data_test.csv", function(data) {

//Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select("body")
       .selectAll("svg")
       .data(data)
       .enter()
       .append("svg")
       .attr("width", w)
       .attr("height", h)

// Cat 1         
svg.selectAll("uni")
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append("line")
   .attr("x1", w/2)
   .attr("y1", h - stemL)
   .attr("x2", function(d) {return w/2 + length1 * d.uni * Math.sin(angle1);})
   .attr("y2", function(d) {return (h - stemL) - length1 * d.uni * Math.cos(angle1); })
   .style("stroke", "steelblue")
   .style("stroke-width", 5);

});
```

As a result I get the expected 3 SVG (see data_test.csv below), but d3 draws each line of the data in every SVG on top of each other, instead of line 1 in SVG 1, line 2 in SVG 2, etc.

What am I missing??? :-/

Many many thanks for your help in advance!

Ewa

data_test.csv:

```
country,uni
Sweden,1.6
Germany,1
Poland,0.7
```

Comment: Have a look at the [nested selections tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/), which I believe is what you're looking for here. Not sure what you mean by pie layout though -- it doesn't look like you're using the pie layout.

Comment: Thanks for the link Lars! So I get the impression that I indeed need something else than .data(data) in the Cat 1/ LINE section. Tried .data(function(d) { return d; }), but this didn't help either! :-/

Comment: P.S. Removed the part with the "pie layout" in my question - was misleading..

Comment: Hmm, you don't actually have a nested structure there -- might be easier to do it with a loop. That is, loop through the rows and draw SVG/line for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have "`.data(data)`" two times. One in "Create SVG element" ano one in "Cat 1" and that seems to be reason that d3 draws each line of the data in every SVG.  "`.data(data)`" in "Create SVG element" is enough.

When "Cat 1" is changed to this

```
svg.append("line")
.attr("x1", w/2)
.attr("y1", h - stemL)
.attr("x2", function(d) {return w/2 + length1 * d.uni * Math.sin(angle1);})
.attr("y2", function(d) {return (h - stemL) - length1 * d.uni * Math.cos(angle1); })
.style("stroke", "steelblue")
.style("stroke-width", 5);
```

I get three different lines.

[edit]
You can also write everything like this:

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
        .selectAll("svg")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
        .append("line")
        .attr("x1", w/2)
        .attr("y1", h - stemL)
        .attr("x2", function(d) {return w/2 + length1 * d.uni * Math.sin(angle1);})
        .attr("y2", function(d) {return (h - stemL) - length1 * d.uni * Math.cos(angle1); })
        .style("stroke", "steelblue")
        .style("stroke-width", 5);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When I remove .data(data) in the Cat 1/ LINE section, nothing is drawn. I need to bind data as I'm referring to it, but I indeed think now that it needs to be something else then .data(data). Tried .data(function(d) { return d; }) with no success.

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME!!!! Many thanks for this!! I forgot to delete "selectAll("uni")"... I would have never figured this out! What is the rational behind this? What's your thinking why you don't need to bind the data again? I would like to learn from that!

Comment: Thank you, you can also vote up my answer :) Data is already bound to svg so you don't need to add it again

Comment: As simple as that, I see... I can't vote you up unfortunately! :-( Don't have enough reputation...

Comment: The d3 adventure continues! :) Next issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638417/d3-or-javascript-use-local-variable-in-another-function. Maybe you can help again? :)