# d3 (or JavaScript): use local variable in another function

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, scope

I'm stuck in d3.js.

I'm drawing multiple SVG canvas with lines, where the length of the lines is determined by data. Each row of the data is mapped to its own SVG.

What's not working properly is to draw a line at the end of another line. My code worked before I entered the data. But now as soon as I add a data value (e.g. d.uni), the second line is always drawn at the same position, namely at the last position determined by JS.

Here is the code:

```
var w = 300;
var h = 250;
var stemL = 100;
var catX1 = 0;
var catY1 = 0;
var catX2 = 0;
var catY2 = 0;
var subCatX1 = 0;
var subCatY1 = 0;
var length1 = 80;
var length2 = 40;
var angle1 = -1.2;
var angleF = 0.7;

d3.csv("data_test.csv", function(data) {

//Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select("body")
.selectAll("svg")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("svg")
.attr("width", w)
.attr("height", h)
.append("g")  

// Cat 1          
svg.append("line")
   .attr("x1", function() {catX1 = w/2; return catX1})
   .attr("y1", function() {catY1 = h - stemL; return catY1})
   .attr("x2", function(d) {catX2 = catX1 + length1 * d.uni * Math.sin(angle1); return catX2})
   .attr("y2", function(d) {catY2 = catY1 - length1 * d.uni * Math.cos(angle1); return catY2})
   .style("stroke", "steelblue")
   .style("stroke-width", 5);

// Cat 1 - uni Acc    
svg.append("line")
   .attr("x1", catX2)
   .attr("y1", catY2)
   .attr("x2", function(d) {subCatX2 = catX2 + length2 * d.uniAcc * Math.sin(angle1 - angleF); return subCatX2;})
   .attr("y2", function(d) {subCatY2 = catY2 - length2 * d.uniAcc * Math.cos(angle1 - angleF); return subCatY2;})
   .style("stroke", "steelblue")
   .style("stroke-width", 3);           

});
```

So, is this a problem of local vs. global variables or does it have to do with the fact that I'm drawing multiple SVG?

This is how it should look like: [image: Two lines per SVG] (but with varying lengths of the first line).

How can I achieve this?

Your help is very much appreciated!

Thanks
Ewa

Here is the "data_test.csv":

```
country,uni,uniAcc
Sweden,1.6,1.1
Germany,1,1.5
Poland,0.7,1
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Something like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955)? I'm just having a hard time understanding why you're using several SVGs.

Comment: It will be kind of a tree per country. They will all look different, depeneding on the data.

Comment: In any case, you should really switch to a completely data-driven design that gets all the coordinates from the data. Computing them inside accessors as you're doing at the moment is a bit cumbersome.

Comment: Added a picture for you to see what is intended. I can't get all the coordinates from the data as this is a custom shape..

Comment: The idea there is to have something that computes the coordinates from the data -- this is usually referred to as a layout. Take the [pie chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887235) for example. The data doesn't contain the angles etc, but the pie chart layout computes them. Then the result of that computation can be used directly to draw the chart.

Comment: Sure, but first I don't want a pie chart. Hence, second I need to write the layout myself!

Comment: Yes, you would need to write the layout yourself. This is what I'm suggesting to do.

Comment: When I would be able to write a layout myself, I wouldn't ask stupid questions here! :D ;) I'm new to programming...

Comment: This is what you're going to have to do I'm afraid, whether you like it or not :) Anything else would end being essentially the same but more messy. You may find it easier to start with a different project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done this way:

```
var w = 300;
var h = 250;
var stemL = 100;
var catX1 = 0;
var catY1 = 0;
var catX2 = 0;
var catY2 = 0;
var subCatX1 = 0;
var subCatY1 = 0;
var length1 = 80;
var length2 = 40;
var angle1 = -1.2;
var angleF = 0.7;

catX1 = w/2;
catY1 = h - stemL;



d3.csv("data_test.csv", function(data) {

var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
            .y(function(d) { return d.y; });


//Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select("body")
          .selectAll("svg")
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append("svg")
          .attr("width", w)
          .attr("height", h)
          .append("g");



svg.append("path").attr("d", function(d){



var lineData = [ { "x": catX1,   
                   "y": catY1 }, 

                { "x": function() {catX2 = catX1 + length1 * d.uni * Math.sin(angle1); return catX2}(),  
                  "y": function() {catY2 = catY1 - length1 * d.uni * Math.cos(angle1); return catY2}() }, 

                { "x": function() {catX2 = catX1 + length1 * d.uni * Math.sin(angle1); return catX2}(),  
                  "y": function() {catY2 = catY1 - length1 * d.uni * Math.cos(angle1); return catY2}() },

                { "x": function() {subCatX2 = catX2 + length2 * d.uniAcc * Math.sin(angle1 - angleF); return subCatX2;}(),  
                  "y": function() {subCatY2 = catY2 - length2 * d.uniAcc * Math.cos(angle1 - angleF); return subCatY2;}() }
                ];  

                return lineFunction(lineData);
})
 .style("stroke", "steelblue")
 .style("stroke-width", 3)
 .attr("fill", "none");   



});
```

Here is working version - http://lunobus.com/threelines2/

Comment: You are my absolute HERO!! THESE are exactly the JS skills I need to make up urgently! What are the keywords I need to research? Functions and objects in general? Thanks a lot! Cheers

Comment: P.S. If you vote my question up I'll finally have enough reputation to vote your answer up! :)

Comment: Thank you! You can learn a lot from this - http://www.youtube.com/user/d3Vienno/videos?flow=list&sort=da&view=0